# wx python 3.0.2 classic SetFocus blows

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I had a Progress class that was working fine in 2.8.12.1 unicode:

```
class Progress(bolt.Progress):
    """Progress as progress dialog."""
    def __init__(self,title=_(u'Progress'),message=u' '*60,parent=None,
            style=wx.PD_APP_MODAL|wx.PD_ELAPSED_TIME|wx.PD_AUTO_HIDE|wx.PD_SMOOTH,
            abort=False, onAbort=None):
        if abort:
            style |= wx.PD_CAN_ABORT
            self.fnAbort = onAbort
        self.dialog = wx.ProgressDialog(title,message,100,parent,style)
        self.dialog.SetFocus() #### line 1295 in the traceback is here ####
        bolt.Progress.__init__(self)
        self.message = message
        self.isDestroyed = False
        self.prevMessage = u''
        self.prevState = -1
        self.prevTime = 0
```

(bolt.Progress has no wx in it)

In 3.02 however blows with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
  File "bash\basher\__init__.py", line 2670, in _refresh_installers_if_needed
    with balt.Progress(_(u'Refreshing Installers...'),u'\n'+u' '*60, abort=canCancel) as progress:
  File "bash\balt.py", line 1295, in __init__
    self.dialog.SetFocus()
  File "C:\_\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx\_core.py", line 10129, in SetFocus
    return _core_.Window_SetFocus(*args, **kwargs)
wx._core.PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "hWnd" failed at ..\..\src\msw\window.cpp(562) in wxWindow::SetFocus(): can't set focus to invalid window
```

Now can anyone spot what is invalid about this window ? As seen the Progress is instantiated in:

```
with balt.Progress(_(u'Refreshing Installers...'),u'\n'+u' '*60, abort=canCancel) as progress:
```

so parent is None - is it because of that ? However why the change in behavior in 3.0.2 ? **EDIT:** well no - passing a non None parent in makes no difference

Incidentally if I remove the SetFocus call it goes on to blow in another setFocus call later on:

```
def doProgress(self,state,message):
    if not self.dialog:
        raise StateError(u'Dialog already destroyed.')
    elif (state == 0 or state == 1 or (message != self.prevMessage) or
        (state - self.prevState) > 0.05 or (time.time() - self.prevTime) > 0.5):
        self.dialog.SetFocus() #### blows here, this self.dialog is really, really invalid ####
        if message != self.prevMessage:
            ret = self.dialog.Update(int(state*100),message)
            if not ret[0]:
                if self.onAbort():
                    raise CancelError
        else:
            ret = self.dialog.Update(int(state*100))
            if not ret[0]:
                if self.onAbort():
                    raise CancelError
        self.prevMessage = message
        self.prevState = state
        self.prevTime = time.time()
```

Not sure if all this hocus pocus is needed or if it could be simplified, but my immediate concern is why the window is invalid.

Comment: Verified on Win7/wxPython Classic 3.0.2. However, what is the use of ``SetFocus()``? According to the style ``wx.PD_APP_MODAL`` the dialog is modal to the app and cannot lose the focus. I noticed something weird, however: If the dialog is created, before the parent has been ``Show()``n, the modal style flag will have no effect (dialog is non-modal).

Comment: Thanks @nepix32 - yes I was suspecting something it had to do with APP_MODAL - I dunno why people used this hocus pocus I did not write that code and as you may have noticed I am a wx n00b. So I actually have 2 questions - why it breaks (while was working fine - should be documented somewhere). And is it needed ? I really don't know.

Comment: Re: creating before the parent - in most of the uses in the code parent is None - dunno (did not find any docs) what the parent internally is in that case - but if it is the "top level window" then it is always shown - except on boot where this progress works fine - hmmmm - must be this AP_MODAL then that broke

Comment: I would just try to comment out the ``SetFocus()``, as it is a no-op at least on 3.0.2, because the progress dialog is modal to its parent anyway.

Comment: @nepix: This fixes it __but__ first I want to understand _why_ this breaks, __plus__, when the application boots, I do show a Progress and then the main frame (or whatever it's called) is not yet shown so that SetFocus may be needed. In general I am not interested in fixing stuff but understanding, documenting __and__ fixing. Give it a try I will reward you ;)

Comment: Created a SSCCE: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uowszxboz3war4n/_set_focus_crash.py?dl=0, posted also in wx-python users: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-users/UuQp57eBalk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows the `ProgressDialog` is now a stock common control (like `MessageDialog`, `FileDialog`, etc.) instead of a generic dialog implemented in wx like it used to be. So it is not a real native window any longer but just a wrapper around a platform API.  So this means that it has no native window handle, and most non-`ProgressDialog`-specific APIs like `SetFocus` will not work.

Comment: Thanks a lot - that answers the question, but are there any workarounds ? Just out of curiosity, I will probably bin the SetFocus calls as they seem (?) unnecessary. Also - since the calls will fail, why on earth are they still in the API ?

Comment: The class derives from wx.Dialog because on some platforms it may still be a generic implementation that really does derive from wx.Dialog. For the other platforms it is kept as a convenience, and all the methods that are intended for normal use on the common dialog are still usable, while use of the ones you don't need is undefined.  This is one of the complexities of using platform specific native widgets instead of generic everywhere.

Comment: Hmm - thanks - should probably emit some kind of warning however - dunno if that would be possible - have some kind of platform depended mixin that overrides those methods and somehow emits a warning. Still not clear about the distinction between native and "stock common control", if you could links me to some docs on that it would be nice :)