# wx python 3.0.2 classic - disable the Cancel button of wx.ProgressDialog

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

More problems with my lovely custom Progress class moving on to wx python 3 (see [wx python 3.0.2 classic SetFocus blows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38012813/281545) for part I)

This:

```
def setCancel(self, enabled=True):
    cancel = self.dialog.FindWindowById(wx.ID_CANCEL)
    cancel.Enable(enabled)
```

used to work just fine in 2.8.12.1 unicode, while crashes in 3.02 with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bash\balt.py", line 419, in <lambda>
    if onButClick: self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda __event: onButClick())
  File "bash\balt.py", line 1565, in _conversation_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "bash\basher\patcher_dialog.py", line 204, in PatchExecute
    progress.setCancel(False)
  File "bash\balt.py", line 1317, in setCancel
    cancel.Enable(enabled)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Enable'
```

`self.dialog` is a [`wx.ProgressDialog`](https://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.ProgressDialog-class.html). From what I read here in [How to override the “Cancel” button event of a ProgressDialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32783974/281545)

> I suspect the native widget won't allow you to access the Cancel button at all, but I'm not sure.

and from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38017173/281545) by @RobinDunn to my previous question:

> On Windows the ProgressDialog [...] *has no native window handle*, and most non-ProgressDialog-specific APIs like SetFocus will not work.

(emphasis mine)

Does this mean that I cant't disable the cancel button of a progress dialog anymore ?

Comment: on my build the ProgressDialog has no children, so the cancel button isn't exposed. It seems easy enough to reproduce using a wx.Gauge though

Comment: @user2682863: thanks - however using native controls (not sure about the terminology really) is there for a reason - and that is performance. It does make a measurable difference in performance in my app where in some operations I display performance indicators for around a minute. Plus if it can be done with vanilla classes I would certainly prefer that.

Comment: Have you tried `wx.GenericProgressDialog`?

Comment: Thanks @RobinDunn - will try although I want it to still work on wx2 - but what is the difference of the 2 classes ? Also I have the impression that Progress in wx3 is faster (I display a lot of them, changing the messages while scanning some dirs and it goes much faster it seems) - is it my impression ? Would it be the same with wx.GenericProgressDialog ?

Comment: `wx.GenericProgressDialog` is what is used for `wx.ProgressDialog` on the platforms that don't have a native version, so it should be very close in functionality.

Comment: Thanks - but given that windows does have a native version am I not loosing the performance ? If yes, and there is no way of disabling the cancel button of the native dialog (which seems probable and would be a feature request), then I'd rather Destroy the dialog and create a new one without cancel button.